# Which filter does InverseRadon use by default?

Tags: image-processing, options, implementation-details, default

I am using the [`InverseRadon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseRadon.html) function. According to the documentation the function uses a Hann filter and no cutoff (`"CutoffFrequency"->1`) by default. However, if this is given as an option the result is different from the default.

Is their a way to determine which parameters (Filter and cutoff) are used by default?

I have tested the filters listed in the documentation.
The result is closest to the cosine-ramp filter, but not identical.

```
i = Import["http://i.imgur.com/zxKkFP9.png"];(* Sinogram from InverseRadon Documentation *)
filter = {{Automatic, "Default"}, {#1&, "ramp filter with constant slope"},{#1 Cos[#1 \[Pi]]&, "ramp filter multiplied by cosine function"}, {(1+Cos[#1 \[Pi]])/2&, "Hann filter (default)"}, {0.54` +0.46` Cos[#1 \[Pi]]&, "Hamming filter"}, {Sqrt[1/(1+#^(2n))]&, Row@{"Butterworth filter of order ",n}}, {1&, "no filtering"}};
TableForm@Transpose[{Last@#,ImageAdjust@InverseRadon[i,{300,300},Method->{First@#, "CutoffFrequency"->1}]}&/@(filter/.n->2)]
```

[image: Different filters for InverseRadon]

---

Edit:
I have tested @JM's suggestion to use the scaled cosine-ramp filter.

```
ImageDifference@@(ImageAdjust@InverseRadon[i, {300, 300}, Method -> #] & /@ {Automatic, (# (1 + Cos[\[Pi] #])/2 &)})
```

This results a black image image. The two options are almost equal, but not identical. The maximum difference (`Max@ImageData`) is 0.00249. 
This is difference image after an `ImageAdjust`:

[image]

Comment: Try this: `ImageAdjust[InverseRadon[i, {300, 300}, Method -> (# (1 + Cos[π #])/2 &)]]`. Use `ImageDifference[]` to compare with the result of `ImageAdjust[InverseRadon[i, {300, 300}]]`.

Comment: @J.M. I Have tested your suggestion. The difference between the default and the scaled cosine-ramp filter is very minor and for me negligible. This solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @jct In other words, the default setting seems to be a Ram.-Lak. (Ramp) filter multiplied by a Hann window.